# Why is template-driven form in Angular asynchronous?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-directive, angular-template-form

[Data flow in template-driven form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaNCF.png)

I found this chart from the official documentation of Angular. It claims that whenever a value in component class is updated, the `ngModel` directive has to queue an async task to update the value for the form control in the next tick. Why waiting?

Comment: What's the problem with it?

Comment: They **queue** the change events. Which means there are *many* events, but if you queue them then the form control can just send a single change event. The form control doesn't know how many. So it does it in the next tick.